# Leet Code Question 438. Find All Anagrams in a String -- Need help understanding hash()

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, hash

**The Question:**
Given a string s and a non-empty string p, find all the start indices of p's anagrams in s.

**The Solution:**

```
class Solution:
    def findAnagrams(self, s: str, p: str) -> List[int]:
        LS, LP, S, P, A = len(s), len(p), 0, 0, []
        if LP > LS:
            return [] # an empty array

        for i in range(LP):
            S, P = S + hash(s[i]), P + hash(p[i])

        if S == P:
            A.append(0)

        for i in range(LP, LS):
            S += hash(s[i]) - hash(s[i - LP]) 
            if S == P:
                A.append(i-LP+1)
        return A
```

This is the solution I have come up with referencing @junaidmansuri 's submission. However I have never used hash() in Python and I am having trouble understanding what it is doing in this function.

I have been playing around with hash() in Jupyter and have noticed that hash('abc') produces a different integer than hash('bca'). It is for this reason that I do not understand how S == P could ever be true if the arrangement of letters in a string affects its hash value.

Furthermore, I also do not see what `S, P = S + hash(s[i]), P + hash(p[i])` is calling. Is this sequence adding ten large integers together for the value of `P`? Really confused.

I great appreciate anyone who has taken the time to read through this and help me.

Comment: Your algorithm isn't correct. in the case of `S == P` you'd need to compare the actual substring. Otherwise you might also encounter a hash-collision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def doit(s):
    return sum([hash(c) for c in s])

doit('abc')
doit('cab')
doit('acb')
```

You always get the same result. So I am thinking based on this you will understand how that algorithme works.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. This helped!!